# If statement to only write new values to PostgreSQL db in Scrapy

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy, psycopg2, scrapyd

I have a Scrapy spider that writes the scraped data to a PostgreSQL database using psycopg2.  I have Scrapyd running and item exporters and everything is setup fine.  I'm scraping the labor section of craigslist for post url, title, and date created.  I want to create notifications on new posts so to achieve this I made the url field in my PostgreSQL database the Primary Key.

The first thing I tried was a try block (which worked in my scraper that I had running using requests and BeautifulSoup.

```py
        try:
            cur.execute( 'INSERT INTO postgres.public.clist (title, url, created, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (title, url, pdate, pdate))
            print('notification')
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            conn.commit()
```

It seems that the Scrapy engine never throws an exception because it always tries to `INSERT INTO` the database.  The second pass of the spider will throw a bunch of errors from psycopg2 for the url field not being unique.

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "clist_url_uindex"
DETAIL:  Key (url)=(https://delaware.craigslist.org/lbg/d/wilmington-truck-cargo-vans-owners-make/6959980210.html) already exists.
```

Next I tried

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    cdate = datetime.strptime(item['dtime'][0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    item_title = item['title'][0]
    item_url = item['url'][0]
    query = 'select * from postgres.public.clist where url = %s'
    self.cur.execute(query, (item_url, ))
    results = self.cur.rowcount
    if results is not 0:
       self.cur.execute( "insert into postgres.public.clist(title, url, created, time) values(%s,%s, %s, %s)", (item_title, item_url, cdate, cdate) )
    else:
       pass
    self.connection.commit()
```

And it still tries to write every record and I get an error for the url field not being unique.

I don't understand why neither of these work, especially the `try` block that worked outside of the Scrapy environment.

I've even seen the process_spider_exception in the middlewares.py file and it already has `pass` in it.

Could someone point me in the right direction to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my issue and while the logic of my if statement was backwards as I posted it, I had it the other way as well and it still wasn't working.

As I said in my comment above I need to `raise DropItem` otherwise the item pipeline will continue to process it.  Once I figured this out I still had issues because I committed what I feel like is a noob mistake and maybe why only one person commented.

While this may seem obvious to most (it does to me now that I figured it out) when dealing with Scrapy and you have your spiders running on Scrapyd.  If you change code for your spiders, pipelines, middleware, etc.  You must re-deploy your spiders for them to utilize the new code.

I figured this out because I decided to completely change the logic of the pipeline to process the items into a csv file then when the spider is closed open the .csv file in a pandas database and drop_duplicates().  Then use pandas to_csv() to save the .csv file.  I was going to read the .csv into the database in my main program that would be calling the spiders.

Once I put all this code in and saved I ran my spider.  Quickly pulled up the log and saw that it was still giving the sql error despite no sql code being in my current project (at least saved locally).  It didn't take long for me to put 2 and 2 together.

TL;DR

When editing code for spiders deployed onto Scrapyd you must deploy the spiders again after saving your new code.  I hope this helps save someone from the countless hours of frustration I've experienced over this.

edit: adding my if statement that worked:

```
        if results is not 0:
            raise DropItem('item') #text inside '' gets put in log
        else:
            self.cur.execute( "insert into postgres.public.clist(title, url, created, time) values(%s,%s, %s, %s)",                        (item_title, item_url, cdate, cdate) )
            self.connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says "Do a lookup of the number of times this url exists in the database. If that number is not zero, then insert the url, otherwise do nothing".

The logic is inverted. You only want to do the insert if the count = 0.

On a side note, you should look into `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I had it backwards.  I've been trying to figure this out all weekend lol.  I've also just found that in scrapy if I don't raise DropItem() the item will never leave the pipeline so I think that is part of my problem too.